# jQuery automatically closes tags on append? e.g. $("<p/>")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I saw this in some code:

```
$("<p/>").append("<div>something</div>").appendTo("body");
```

and noticed that it automatically closed the `p` tag in the generated HTML :

`<p><div>something</div></p>`

I've never seen the selector syntax `$("<p/>")` before. Is this mistake (and Chrome is just guessing what it should be) or is this a feature of jQuery's selector syntax?

Comment: Isn't that *technically* invalid? (I did not know a `<p>` could contain block-level elements...)

Comment: from a semantic point of view it's definetly not valid as p elements should not contain block-level elements. But it's in the responsible of the developer instead of jQuery to take care on this. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$` function is heavily overloaded, even having two functionalities for strings.  If the string is a CSS selector, it will return an object containing the matching elements from the document.  If you open with `<`, it will *create* the element.  jQuery is not creating a *tag*, however.  Elements belong the DOM, tags belong to HTML, which is a serialization of the DOM.

```
$("<p/>")  //Creates a p element
    .append("<div>something</div>") //inserts a child element, which is a div you created
                                    //containing the string "something"
    .appendTo("body"); //tags the newly created paragraph element, with its div child
                       //and inserts it into the DOM as a child of the body element.
```

When you serialize the document, you will wind up with:

```
<body><p><div>something</div></p></body>
```

which shows each element containing its children.

---

If your markup looks like this: `<p/><div>something</div>`, then the `p` and `div` elements are *siblings*.  That would happen if they were appended to the same parent:

```
//Use add to create a new element and add it to the jQuery collection object
//instead of appending it as a child to the p element.
$("<p/>").add("<div>something</div>").appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 6):

it's a feature and jQuery renders the tag correctly.

Comment: I do not consider that "correct" ... AFAIK it will be rendered like `<P/><DIV>...</DIV>` (The `P` is auto-closed before the `DIV`.)

Comment: @pst: In HTML that would be `<p><div>...</div>`, but that's basically the same thing.

Comment: @pst The code is appending a `div` child to a `p` element.  Yours is what `after` would do.

Answer (score 4):

Feature of jQuery look what happens when you make it a self closing tag by default like link

```
$("<link/>").append("<div>something</div>").appendTo("body");
```

It generates

```
<link><div></div></link>
```

which is obviously wrong. But that is what it is being asked to do!

Comment: In other words, jQuery auto-closes tags in the same order they are added while making valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

`<p/>` is shortcut for `<p></p>`

Comment: And `<p>` as well, because when you add  `<p>`  without closing it, the HTML code inspector shows that the that was magically closed.